# Have import-csv not output data

Tags: powershell

So I'm using import-csv to bring in some data to run some PowerCLI commands against. The one thing I don't like that after the first run, the import-csv command will output the data in the csv file before running anything else. I've been searching online but can't find any parameter that could suppress it from auto-outputting this data and was wondering is anyone here knew more about it to help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just write

```
import-csv myfile.csv
```

Then the import-csv cmdlet will, indeed import the CSV file. But since you're not storing the output in a variable or piping the data somewhere, PowerShell will simply output the data to the console.

The answer is that you need to actually do something with the CSV data and not just output it. For example:

```
import-csv myfile.csv | foreach-object {
  # do something with each row
}
```

or

```
$csvData = import-csv myfile.csv
foreach ( $row in $csvData ) {
  # do someting with each row
}
```

Bill

Comment: Yeah i do that but lower in the script so I don't know if that's another cause. But piping it like stated above fixed it. Thanks for the help though!